# redirection route to :back - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect

I have this in my routes file

```
match "/:url" => redirect_to :back, constraints: { url: /^keys.*/ }
```

but I get this message error

```
routes.rb:132: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' (SyntaxError)
  match "/:url" => redirect_to :back, constraints: { url: /^keys.*/ }
                                ^
```

Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? As far as I know, there's no way to redirect back to the referrer in `routes.rb`.

Comment: @zeantsoi yes that's precisely what I wanted to do following the doc : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to

Comment: `redirect_to` is a class method on `ActionController`. It doesn't work in `routes.rb`. I've provided an explanation/solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ambiguous, parentheses to the rescue!

```
match "/:url" => redirect_to(:back), constraints: { url: /^keys.*/ }
```

**Update**

Regarding to there is no `redirect_to`, try:

```
match "/:url" => redirect{|params, request| request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]}, constraints: { url: /^keys.*/ }
```

I didn't tested the code, so let me know if something is wrong.

Comment: I get this message undefined method `redirect_to'

Comment: `redirect_to` is not a method available in `routes.rb`. It's a class method on `ApplicationController`. This code definitively __does not__ work.

Comment: None of this will work. `routes.rb` doesn't have any access to the `params` or `request` of your request. Both answers you've proposed are misleading and entirely incorrect.

Comment: thanks a lot, redirect(:back) erros this `redirect': redirection argument not supported (ArgumentError) but the second proposition worked !

Comment: You're welcome! @zeantsoi please see the documentation about redirect in routes: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Redirection.html

Answer (score 1):

`routes.rb` is agnostic to the state of your application, meaning that it doesn't have access to the referring page. You won't simply be able to invoke `redirect_to :back` as you might in a controller.

That said, you could simply implement that precise code within your controller. For instance, you wanted to redirect any requests on `/keys.*/`, which is controlled by, say, `keys_controller.rb`:

```
# app/controllers/keys_controller.rb
class KeysController < ApplicationController 
    before_filter :redirect

    private

    def redirect
        redirect_to :back
    end
end
```

This would catch any requests on any action on `KeysController` and redirect to the referring page.

**UPDATE**:

To redirect to your defined root (assuming you've explicitly defined one), simple point your redirect to the application root:

```
match "/:url", to: redirect('/'), constraints: { url: /keys.*/ }
```

Comment: Ok I know I can do that, but I find it more natural to redirect from the route file. I read in the doc that I can do something like `get '/stories', to: redirect('/posts')` .I want to that but either redirecting to the root page or to the backward page. Is it possible ?

Comment: It's not possible. Again, `routes.rb` plays a unique role within the MVC framework where it doesn't know about the state of your application at runtime. The correct way to redirect back to the referrer is in the controller as I've demonstrated above.

Comment: Thank you . So I put this `match "/:url", to: redirect('/profiles'), constraints: { url: /keys.*/ }` and it worked fine, how can I redirect to the `root` ?